# Databricks delta live tables stuck when ingest file from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, databricks, data-ingestion, delta-live-tables

I'm new to databricks and just created a delta live tables to ingest 60 millions json file from S3. However the input rate (the number of files that it read from S3) is stuck at around 8 records/s, which is very low IMO. I have increased the number of worker/core in my delta live tables but the input rate stays the same.

Is there any config that I have to add to increase the input rate for my pipeline?

Comment: What are you using for ingesting that files? Autoloader (cloudFiles) or just `spark.read`? Is the file compressed with gzip or something else?

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen did you got the fix?